# How to find charPosition=750, lineNumber=1, columnNumber=751 in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I got an error in SAP PO on this line: charPosition=750, lineNumber=1, columnNumber=751

How can I find this line in Notepad++?

Comment: `lineNumber=1` how could it be clearer? At the bottom of Npp window, you have the line number and the column number displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your log file, it's a bit unclear where the error is. It's probably at column 751 or 1501.

Assuming it's at the first line of your log file, you can jump straight to it using the Go To... function:

*Search -> Go To... (Ctrl+G)*

Select *Offset*, enter 751 in the *You Want to go to :* textfield, and click *Go*.

The offset is always from the start of the file, not the line. So if you want to jump to a particular column on another line, you need to first place your cursor at the start of that line, and then in the *Go To...* dialog add your current offset (*You are here :*) to the column you want to jump to.